# can't send data from react-native app to python server

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, react-native, socket.io

I'm doing an application that send and recieve data with python socket server. The application written with react-native. Everytime i connect and try send/recieve data it give that error: GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Mlquqm0 HTTP/1.1

actually ı send a data like "hello server" but server recieve that error.

python socket working in a ubuntu server. i tried this on a python client and it's work but not react-native client.

```
server.py:
import socket
import sys
import ast
import os
import time

HOST = ip
PORT = port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# socket.socket: must use to create a socket.
# socket.AF_INET: Address Format, Internet = IP Addresses.
# socket.SOCK_STREAM: two-way, connection-based byte streams.
print('socket created')

# Bind socket to Host and Port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as err:
    print
    'Bind Failed, Error Code: ' + str(err[0]) + ', Message: ' + err[1]
    sys.exit()

print('Socket Bind Success!')

# listen(): This method sets up and start TCP listener.
s.listen(10)
print('Socket is now listening')

while 1:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('Connect with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
    buf = conn.recv(64)
    buf = buf.decode()
    command = str(buf)
    print(command)
    nickname,password,command = command.split()
    gazoz = str(nickname) + " " + str(password) + " " + str(command)
    input = open("input.txt","a+",encoding="utf-8")
    input.write(str(gazoz) + "\n")
    input.close()
    print(nickname)
    time.sleep(2)
    if os.path.isfile("connection/us_" + nickname + ".txt"):
        data = open("connection/us_" + nickname + ".txt","r",encoding="utf-8")
        msg = data.read()
        print(msg)
        data.close()
        os.remove("connection/us_" + nickname + ".txt")
        msg = str.encode(msg)
        if len(msg) == 0:
            msg = "pek bisi yok"
            msg = str.encode(msg)

    conn.send(msg)
```

s.close()

react native client

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io("ip:port");
        socket.connect();
        socket.emit("hello server");
        socket.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this ?

```
import SocketIOClient from "socket.io-client/dist/socket.io"; 
const socket = await SocketIOClient(url); 
socket.on("connect", () => { console.log("connected") });
```